# regular expression find strings with certain pattern in R

Tags: regex, r

I have some strings here and they are:

```
12ABC3, 2ABC45, ABC 56, uhyABC, REGEXP ...
```

The objective is as long as there is 'ABC' in a string (not 'BCA' or 'BAC') it should return TRUE when using 'grepl'

So the output should be

```
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `fixed = TRUE` in your call to `grepl`.

```
> x <- c("12ABC3", "2ABC45", "ABC 56", "uhyABC", "REGEXP", "BCA", "CAB")
> grepl("ABC", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The `fixed` argument definition is

> logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is. Overrides all conflicting arguments.

Comment: Why is `grepl("ABC", x)` without `fixed = TRUE` insufficient?  Does it fail in some circumstances?

Comment: @Frank - In general, it's safer because when `fixed = TRUE`, all other arguments to `grepl` are ignored.  `fixed` basically tells R that we're not using a regex now, and to match the string in `pattern` exactly.

Comment: The help file says that using `fixed` can be faster in some circumstances

Comment: +1 For the added information about speed and reliability.  I commented in hopes that I might learn something/correct my understanding, as I didn't think using `fixed = TRUE` was important here. Now, I see why it is a good idea, though not strictly necessary in this circumstance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following.

```
> x <- c('12ABC3', '2ABC45', 'ABC 56', 'uhyABC', 'REGEXP')
> grepl('ABC', x, fixed=T)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> x[grepl('ABC', x, fixed=T)]
# [1] "12ABC3" "2ABC45" "ABC 56" "uhyABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this expression: `\w*ABC[\w\s]*`

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dB1pO6/1)

`\w*` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` `*` will make it match from 0 to unlimited times.

`\w\s]*` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]` this one includes space in your forth expression and again `*` will make it match from 0 to unlimited times.